# diagnostics KVM switch in QNX 6.5

Tags: qnx

I have KVM(ATEN CS 1642) switch and connected to it usb-mouse, usb-keyboard and two dvi displays. KVM controls switching between two computers (QNX 6.5). I need to get information about connected input-output devices(mouse, keyboard, displays). Operating system utilities determine only emulated switch devices. I.e. call hidview displays Aten mouse and Aten keyboard, even if they actually pull out of the KVM. Can I get a list of actually connected IO devices programmatically?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have the USB device connected, you can use `usb -vvv` for more detailed information.